# What kind of json starts with length

Tags: java, json

I am getting a json array from server like below

```
69[0,{"dabcdefghij":{},"abcdefg":"20","abcdefghijklmn":"10, AB-11111"}]
```

I know the data inside [ ] is json. But the server is also sending the length of the json.
Right now i am finding the first occurence of **[** and parsing the json.

Is it the right way? I am using gson. Is there a better method to parse this?

Comment: Where does your "json" come from ? This looks like a home-made protocol with message content encoded as json. I might also be a server error.

Comment: Someone forgot an echo in code after "debugging" :))

Comment: I think you should find the one who developed this server software and kick his butt real hard.

Comment: The server is trolling you; no kind of JSON starts with length. There's exactly one kind of JSON. Find whomever wrote it and make them fix it.

Comment: the server is calibre, from source code I think its using json.dumps in python

Comment: It's not legal JSON.  Of course, a server can send whatever it wants and claim that's its spec.  It's just not JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`69[0,{"dabcdefghij":{},"abcdefg":"20","abcdefghijklmn":"10, AB-11111"}]` is not valid JSON according to [json.org](http://www.json.org/) as it's not object nor an array.

> JSON is built on two structures:
>
> - A collection of name/value pairs. In various languages, this is
>     realized as an object, record, struct, dictionary, hash table, keyed
>     list, or associative array.
> - An ordered list of values. In most languages, this is realized as an
>     array, vector, list, or sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i guess the server is sending length because it is streaming the json.  But the streaming api's somehow do not need the length to get the json objects, that is why i got confused